# Send and receive multiple data without form being blocked by query

Tags: .net, vb.net, executenonquery

I am trying to make a program that process data that comes but send it to a container first before executing the query so the program still could receive data if the previous data has not been sent successfully.

basically

```
if NewData.Exists() :
ProcessNewDataToContainer()
```

and then

```
while Container.isNotEmpty() :
BuildQuery()
ExecuteQuery()
```

I was also looking for a way to do the query everytime it was called so it would be one straight process like

```
if NewData.Exists() :
    ProcessNewDataToContainer()
    BuildQuery()
    ExecuteQuery()
```

but I haven't find the right way to do it since everytime the query is executed, the program is blocked from doing the query while new data is still being sent to the program. so the program doesn't receive all data because the query is blocking it from processing new data

is there any way that I could do to make sure the program would receive all data and process it to database without the program being blocked by the query process?

Answer (score 0):

Why not make sure the data is sent by:

Using
End Using

that way you control when the connection for the query is disposed/closed

Comment: yeah, I used that too but my problem is while the data is being sent, another one is also being sent at the same time but the executequery process is still blocking the form so the program still unable to process the incoming data

in other words, there's more incoming data than the available processing speed